# How to get the number of the current image clicked on in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

Ok, so suppose. I have ten images in `documents.images` array. When I click on an image. How do I get an alert telling me what image I have clicked on.

**EDIT**
The reason that I want the index of the image I clicked on is because I am trying to bind it to an event and the previous way doesn't seem to work

```
document.images[i].addEventListener("click", function(){MakeMove(i)}, false);
```

This statement is in a for loop, and I intended it to bind to every image but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Any chance you're using jQuery? With it such thing becomes trivial.

Comment: can you share the code what you have tried?

Comment: nope, not using jquery yet, and  for this part of the assignment I believe it would be best to find a non jquery solution.

Comment: edited my question with some more details

Comment: Your original code can't work due to scope issues.

Comment: So, if I added some kind of globalcounter or closure, I guess it would work?

Comment: Probably the reason your code doesn't work is because the callback function doesn't take i as a parameter, and therefore lacks a stable reference to the intended index; whenever it's called it uses the last value that i takes, i.e. the index of the last image in the list. To fix, define your listener adder as a function, myListenerAdder, that takes "index" as a param, and then call myListenerAdder(i) for each iteration of the loop

Comment: Thank you, I did what you suggested and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is pure JavaScript way to do that:

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        var image = document.images[i];
        image.setAttribute("index", i + "");
        image.onclick = function() {
            var index = this.getAttribute("index");
            alert("This is image #" + index);
        };
    }
};
```

The trick is assigning custom attribute with the index, then read that attribute.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/uUF8x/).

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the bottom of the html file, just before the  closing tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function listen(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) { // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
        var r = elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
        return r;
    }
}


listen("click", document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], function(event) {
     var images = document.images,
         clicked = event.target;
    for(var i =0, il = images.length; i<il;i++) {
        if(images[i] === clicked) {
            return alert("You clicked on the " + (i + 1) + "th image");
        }
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        var image = document.images[i];
        image.onclick = function() {
            var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.images);
            alert(Array.indexOf(images,this));
        }
    };
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmendes/8LUzg/1/

If you want it to work on old browsers too add the function under Compatibility on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf